# Генерировать QR c vCard на php

Tags: php, qr

Пытаюсь генерировать QR код с vCard на PHP

```
<?php 
   $vCard = "BEGIN:VCARD\n
   VERSION:3.0\n
   FN:Иван Иванов\n
   TEL:+380111111111\n
   URL:http://google.com.ua\n
   END:VCARD"; 

  echo "<img src='https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?cht=qr&chs=200x200&chl='.$vCard.'>";
?>
```

Сканер выдает пустоту:(

```html
<img src="https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?cht=qr&chs=200x200&chl=BEGIN:VCARD\nVERSION:3.0\nFN:Иван Иванов\nTEL:+380111111111\nURL:http://google.com.ua\nEND:VCARD>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Приветствую!

Итоговый вариант:

```
<?php
$vCard = urlencode("BEGIN:VCARD\nVERSION:3.0\nFN:Иван+Иванов\nTEL:+380111111111\nURL:http://google.com.ua\nEND:VCARD");
$url = "https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?cht=qr&chs=200x200&chl=$vCard";
?>

<img src="<?= $url; ?>" alt="">
```

Все `\n`надо заменить на `%0A`либо пропускать url через `urlencode`
[Возможно будет полезно!](http://fisherwebdev.com/wordpress/2010/05/21/vcards-as-qr-codes-with-google-image-chart-api/)

Comment: пожалуйста, добавьте пояснения, чтобы было ясно, что вы исправили

Comment: Так читает сплошной текст в кавычках, а нужно vCard :(

Comment: @AndreyVitovtov не совсем понимаю, что именно нужно? Сейчас у вас в chl параметр попадает текст из переменной $vCard.

Comment: Нужно чтобы было как вот здесь http://olefirenko.net/qr-code-generating/ при сканировании кода, добавить контакт, а не просто текст. Для этого и нужен vCard

Comment: @AndreyVitovtov посмотрите **UPD2**, в таком виде код должен работать как нужно ;)

Comment: @socode к сожалению UPD2, как изначально сканер выдает пустоту

Comment: @AndreyVitovtov пустоту выдаёт где? При визуализации QR или при сканировании кода?

Comment: @socode при сканировании кода

Comment: @AndreyVitovtov вам необходимо пропустить URL через функцию urlencode, для того чтобы закодировать знаки переноса строки. Либо вручную заменить все `\n` на `%0A`